# skype installation in ubuntu12.04

Tags: skype

if i installed error is showing..

```
varmuk@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
[sudo] password for varmuk: 
dpkg: error processing skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot the change the directory to where the debian package is stored.

If you downloaded it into `Downloads` the 1st command needs to be:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```